# 12V Jacob's Ladder circuit introducing noise on input and messing with PSU

Tags: capacitor, noise, ripple, filtering

I have made a Jacob's Ladder display for fun.
I have no oscilloscope to give exact details, but there must be some kind of noise or high-voltage ripple that is resetting the display of my Lab Power Supply (based on DPS5015 buck module).

**I have attached a pic of the circuit. Is there some kind of diode/cap/inductor I could use at the input to stop the spikes/noise from resetting my PSU display?**

*The circuit is meant to run off a car battery, but that is not ideal for me. I imagine a battery won't care one bit about this noise.*

*(I understand this is likely a fault of the PSU for not handling the noise/spikes properly. I plan on using a 12V laptop brick I've salvaged when I make a proper enclosure. But if it's as simple as adding some components, I may as well, to eliminate any possible issues with the laptop brick (a Lite-On SMPS).)*

On a side note, the circuit says "12V input, 5A minimum" but I've measured under many different scenarios for spark gap etc, and it seems to remain constant at about 1.3A. Due to this, I imagine the 2.7A laptop brick I play to use will be adequate. I'll install proper protection (on top of the laptop brick's own).

[image: Jacob's Ladder Mk2 Schematic]

Comment: A jacob's ladder is a spark gap. That generates all manner of EMI. (Not to mention soft x-rays.)

Comment: @jonk do you think electromagnetic interference is resetting the PSU's display from across the room? This isn't a very impressive jacob's ladder as far as they go.

Comment: No way to know for sure. I'm relying upon your own way of organizing the information you presented, adding to that a few things I know generally. Whether or not my general knowledge provides a valid hypothesis for what you present is a matter of more experimentation. Make a prediction on this basis -- move things closer to each other, for example, and it should occur more frequently/with less mean time between events, for example. If that pans out, since I don't know the keV involved I can't speculate about the soft x-ray side. Anything over 1 keV is by definition entering soft x-ray range.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the simplicity of the circuit, the power supply current it takes from the supply will be extremely irregular. It will take a current pulse from the supply each time the darlington transistor is switched on.

When powered from a car battery that should be of little concern as a car battery has an extremely low internal series resistance so the battery's voltage will barely drop when a current pulse occurs. Most of the drop is likely to be in the wires you use to connect to the battery (unless you're using very thick wires).

A switched mode power supply relies on its output capacitors to handle current pulses. Most switched mode power supplies aren't designed for and/or don't work well with a pulsed load as their output filtering capacitors are dimensioned for filtering out the switching frequency of the switching powersupply itself, usually these are switching at around 50 kHz to 200 kHz. That needs a (relatively) small value capacitor but with a low series resistance (low ESR).

What I would do is add some measure to "isolate" the circuit from the supply so that the supply will not be bothered by the pulses. I would try this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3zWc5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For the diode use any diode you have available which can handle at least 3 A, it can be a Schottky diode but does not have to be. For the capacitor a 4700 uF 16 V electrolytic capacitor is what you need. The 4700 uF is just my guess, maybe 1000 uF will work as well.

If this still gives issues then you could try adding a resistor in series with the diode, start with a 1 ohm, 5 Watt one similar to the one in your schematic.

Comment: use a ground plane ; solder the 4,700uF cap (-) wire to the ground plane, with 1cm lead.. Then connect the Jacobs Ladder to the ground plane.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf what do you mean by ground plane here?

Comment: @Mono a ground plane isn't really needed here, it will work with and without a ground plane. A ground plane is more for RF (radio frequency) type circuits which this circuit isn't. Yes it will generate RF signals (all electrical sparks do) but we're not trying to transmit them. Unless analogsystemsrf can come up with a good reason to have a groundplane, I'd just ignore his remark.

Comment: No luck so far with diode+4.7mF circuit above. Adding the resistor in series with the diode drops almost 2V, with a significant effect on the performance. I'll have some 12V/5A laptop bricks in a few days to try. You can see the display glitching and then crashing here:  https://giphy.com/gifs/jacobs-ladder-power-supply-issues-33HoV03DFRrBACsRlz  -  Often the buttons stop responding or are slow to respond. Sometimes it takes a few seconds, sometimes it turns white right away. This PSU consists of a buck converter and ST microcontroller, connected to a display panel and button panel separately.